# How to get data range in sql query form excell cells in ODBC source

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

I am getting data by power query ODBC source.

I have to manually edit data each time I want to get next month.

`where REAL_ARRIVAL_DATE between to_date( '20190101' ) and to_date( '20190131' )`

Is there a possibility to put that data ranges in cell or cells or in form when refreshing query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the first day of the month in SQL language use

```
date_add(date_add(LAST_DAY(now()),interval 1 DAY),interval -1 MONTH)
```

For the last day of the month

```
LAST_DAY(now())
```

So your formula should be:

```
where REAL_ARRIVAL_DATE between date_add(date_add(LAST_DAY(now()),interval 1 DAY),interval -1 MONTH) and LAST_DAY(now())
```

In this way, you don't have to change the code every month

Or if you want to change manually the date make a query with parameters.

In excel open connection properties like the picture below

[image]

and put in the where clause a question mark

```
where REAL_ARRIVAL_DATE between ? and ?
```

Press ok and there will appear 2 popups, that will ask which cell do you want to reference for the dates, like below

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge with me. I just had to change query from ODCB source to MS Query to change Query into Connection, as I could not access definition fields - they were grey out.